# C++ read Serial input to String

Tags: c++, c, input, console, serial-port

I need to get the Serial input from the console to a String.
When the User types "xyz" into the console and presses enter, the String "input" should be defined as "xyz". From then I'll interpret the String.
This is what I currently have:

Defintion:

```
char input[] = {0};
char bufferChar[] = {0};
```

Use:

```
bool canInput = true;
while(canInput == true) {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    char bufferChar2 = Serial.read();
    bufferChar[1] = bufferChar2;
    strcpy(input[1], input[1]);
    strcat(input[1], bufferChar[1]);
    Serial.print(input);
    tft.print(input);
  }
}
```

I am new to c, so sorry if this code is bad.
Thanks in advace,
Linus

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: @harry added my current state

Comment: This looks more like C++, not C.  Are you programming in C# or *managed* C++?

Comment: Since the serial port is not standard in C or C++, which library?  Which platform?  Embedded?  Direct access to the UART?

Comment: @Thomas Working with Arduino, that should be a variaton of c++. Not sure on that point though.

Comment: Now that you've established the platform, which operating system?  Arduino?  Android? WinCE? Micrium? Linux? None?  The operating system may provide API to access the serial port.

Comment: Did you set the serial port properties, baud rate, stop bit, parity, etc. the same as the terminal or vice-versa?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for the unclarity. Im using Windows, but run the program on the Arduino. I use the serial Monitor of my PC for the inputs. I print onto that console and a tft-screen, but thats not important.

Comment: There is no standard OS for embedded systems; usually Arduino is an embedded system.  Your PC should be connected to the Arduino via USB or RS232 connector.  You may want to search the internet for "C++ arduino serial port" for more examples of how to set up the serial port and how to use it.  My next question was about interrupts...

Comment: I connect to the Arduino (Mega 2560) using a USB cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char bufferChar[] = {0};
```

This declares an array with one element.

```
bufferChar[1] = bufferChar2;
```

This attempts to set the value of the 2nd element in an one element array. Buffer overflow. Undefined behavior.

```
strcpy(input[1], input[1]);
```

This makes no sense. Besides the dubious reason behind wanting to `strcpy`() something on top of itself, `input` is a `char` array, so `input[1]` is a single `char` value, while `strcpy()` takes `char *` arguments.

This line must've made your compiler spew a bunch of warnings and/or errors. Please don't ignore diagnostic messages from your compiler. That's the compiler telling you that you're doing it wrong.

```
strcat(input[1], bufferChar[1]);
```

So, we are attempting to `strcat`() another pair of `char`s instead of `char *`s. This is not going to work any better than attempting to `strcpy()` the same thing.

Even if your compiler accepts this, the resulting code will crash, in at least three or four different ways, by my count.

You need to:

1. Declare `input` and `charBuffer` arrays that are of sufficient size, for what you intend to do with them.
2. Pass pointers, not `char`s, to both `strcpy()` (if you need it), and `strcat()`.
3. `char *` parameters, to both `strcpy()` and `strcat()` arrays must be null-terminated strings. It is your responsibility to '\0'-terminate each parameter. Although there are several ways to get this "for free", if you're in doubt, explicitly 0-terminate them.